# How to find out whether libav is built on MPI/LAM?

Tags: audio, cluster, parallel-processing

Just what the title states ; I expect to be doing a touch of audio cleanup/format switching. My plan is to try to do this with libav. Apparently such processing is fairly intensive; hence I would like to try this using distributed processing ... which brings up the question -

How do I find out whether libav lends itself to distributed/cluster processing?

Answer (score 1):

How do you plan on distributed processing using `libavcodec`/`libavformat`? It's a very efficient, low level C-based encoder/decoder library, but it's never been targeted towards distributed coding.

Because that would mean it'd have to implement network communication protocols, etc. and that isn't really in the spirit of such a library. It'd be too much overhead.

---

This is not to say that somebody could write a middleware software that would bundle and synchronize multiple libav installations on distributed machines, but I doubt there is a thing like that.

On the other hand, in the professional league, there are alternatives. On OS X for example, there is the combination of [Compressor](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2897) and [Qmaster](http://documentation.apple.com/en/appleqmaster/usermanual/#chapter=preface&section=1&hash=apple_ref:doc:uid:TempBookID-ReplacedWhenAssociatingWithMessierRevision-CH1-SW1), which are made for that purpose:

> Compressor 2 can accelerate processing by distributing the work to multiple computers. All you need is access to more than one computer and Compressor 2 installed with either DVD Studio Pro 4 or Final Cut Studio

One can also use Qmaster for any other Unix command line program. At the moment I can't recall a Windows alternative for that, but there surely are some.

Comment: I wondered whether it supported distributed proc (+: hence the question. If it had been supported, I'd looked twards a 2-3 node home-grown cluster using my old boxes

Comment: @Everyone Hm.. As far as I can tell, not out of the box. I mean, depending on what kind of videos you have you might just remote control execution over some shell scripts. Processing *one* video over a distributed system is a harder thing to do :)